# Reordering (reposition) data models based on tableview sections and rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Let say I have few sections which are weekdays and few rows which my workouts for the day.

So the structure could be next

```
Monday section 0
Workout 1 (row 0)
Workout 2 (row 1)

Tuesday section 1
Workout 1 (row 0)
Workout 2 (row 1)
```

So when I move cell between sections I want reposition my elements actually workouts in the sections.

Currently I have data model

```
class Workout {
var position: Int
}
```

So now when I moved a cell from one section to another I need to cycle over my `[workouts]` arrays to recalculate positions in source section and in destination section.

Maybe there is some beautiful solution such as `List` with first and last elements which I can simple re bind or any other.

I see that there is no List [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html)

Comment: Do you really need the position in the class? You can get the index always from the data source array.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a struct `Session` or `Schema` or similar that has a date and a `Workout` property and use that in your data source array?

Comment: thanks for suggestions! yea I need position as I need set ordered chain of workouts one by one. so I guess the best solution then will be write custom list? or actually use PGDev solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle reordering in a `tableView`, you can simply use its `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

**Example:**

We'll be using the below `array` as `tableView's` `dataSource`:

```
var arr = [["First", "Second"], ["Third", "Fourth"]]
```

To modify the `dataSource` when cells are reordered, use `tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:)` method and change the `dataSource` according to the `sourceIndexPath` and `destinationIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let val = arr[sourceIndexPath.section][sourceIndexPath.row]
    arr[destinationIndexPath.section][destinationIndexPath.row] = val
    arr[sourceIndexPath.section].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
}
```

Also, as mentioned there is nothing like `List` in `Swift`. You've to use the `Array` to handle that.